# 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'Boost'

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-lucene

I'am trying to us boost function for busting some results in a sitecore search. You can see the code from bellow:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();
predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Content.Equals(text).Boost(10));
```

When I use .Boost(10)  I got the following error:

> 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'Boost' and no extension
>   method 'Boost' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be
>   found

What did I have done wrong? Or should I use some specific library?

Comment: Did you try setting your boost as a `float` value, e.g. `.Boost(10f)` ?

Comment: Do you have `using Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq;`?

Comment: @Gatogordo  10x it's working now

Comment: Glad I could help. Copied as answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put using `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq;` in your code. The extension method resides there.